# Custom categorical colorbar in Pandas scatter plot

Tags: python, pandas, plot, data-visualization

I have a pandas dataframe. I'd like to make a scatter plot of two different quantites and color the scatter plot points by category.

I have  dictionary that describes the mapping to colors, and I'd like to use that dictionary.

Here's what I have:

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

weights = [1.0, 1.1, 1.3, 2.6, 5.1] 
volumes = [2.1, 4.3, 2.6, 2.7, 9.6]
fruits = ['apple', 'banana', 'banana', 'apple', 'coconut']

data_dict = {'weight': weights, 'vol': volumes, 'class': fruits}

df = pd.DataFrame(data_dict)

color_dict = {'apple' : 'r', 'banana' : 'yellow', 'coconut' : 'lime'}

plt.scatter(df['weight'], df['vol'], c = [color_dict[i] for i in df['class'].iloc[:]])
plt.xlabel('Weight')
plt.ylabel('Volume')
plt.colorbar()
plt.show()
```

This:

[image: Samle plot]

is the result. I'd like

- a discrete colorbar with the category colors and labels
- with colors specified by a dictionary.

How can this be achieved? Can it be done in pandas, or do I have to use matplotlib commands?

---

**Addition:**

The following one-liner achieves the same result as above in pandas.

```
df.plot(kind="scatter", x="weight", y="vol", c=df['class'].map(color_dict), colorbar=True)
```

Doing:

```
df['class'] = df['class'].astype('category')
df.plot(kind="scatter", x="weight", y="vol", c='class')
```

gives a categorical colormap with labels, but how can I supply my custom colormap?